# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature when using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch-api

I'm trying to get `node-fetch` to work in my typescript project:

```
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';
import * as assert from 'assert';

export class DatabaseConfigurator {
  private url: string;

  getNode (): Promise<string> {
    return fetch(`${this.url}/_membership`).then((response: fetch.Response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((res: any) => {
      assert.equal(res.all_nodes.length, 1);
      return res.all_nodes[0];
    });
  }
}
```

And I get:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "/home/vinz243/compactd/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index"' has no compatible call signatures.
```

When the definition i installed seems ok (`node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index.d.ts`):

```
...

export default function fetch(url: string | Request, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You've imported the entire module rather than the default export, the fetch function. You're trying to call the entire module as a function which doesn't work.

Instead of

```
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

try

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Comment: How do I import the Response definition then?

Comment: nvm, `fetch, {Response}` is the way to go. Thanks!